# Rotation Animation in IE D3 JavaScript CSS3

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, animation, d3.js

The code below, as it is, works perfectly in Chrome (I have it hosted on my local WAMP server). After removing all instances of "@-webkit-", I expected it to work in IE 11. It does not. Interestingly, half of the animation works (the paths fade in and out, but do not rotate). I've spent about 3 hours simply trying to figure out why it doesn't work in IE, and I'm at a loss. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks! (also, if someone want's to take a stab at FireFox too, go for it, I'm at my wit's end for the night :) )

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http:\\localhost\RealDataProject\circleAnimation.css">

</head>
<script src="http:\\localhost\Wordpress-enfoldchild\wp-content\themes\enfold-child\assets\js\jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script>
<script src="http:\\localhost\wordpress-enfoldchild\wp-content\themes\enfold-child\assets\js\d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="svg_dount1" id="svg_donut1" width="800" height="800"></svg> 

<!--<p class="companyName">Badass<br/>Studios</p> -->

<script>

var globalData1 = [];
var globalData2 = [];
var globalData3 = [];
var globalData4 = [];
var test;
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];

d3.tsv("http://localhost/RealDataProject/data.tsv", function(error, data){
    data.forEach(function(d,i){
    globalData1.push([d.value1, d.value2, d.color]);
});
    firstRing(globalData1);
});

d3.tsv("http://localhost/RealDataProject/data2.tsv", function(error, data){
    data.forEach(function(d,i){
    globalData2.push([d.value1, d.value2, d.color]);
});
    secondRing(globalData2);
});

d3.tsv("http://localhost/RealDataProject/data3.tsv", function(error, data){
    data.forEach(function(d,i){
    globalData3.push([d.value1, d.value2, d.color]);
});
    thirdRing(globalData3);
});

d3.tsv("http://localhost/RealDataProject/data4.tsv", function(error, data){
    data.forEach(function(d,i){
    globalData4.push([d.value1, d.value2, d.color]);
});
    fourthRing(globalData4);
});

var cScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var vis = d3.select("#svg_donut1");

function firstRing(data){
var arc = d3.svg.arc() .innerRadius(50) .outerRadius(100) .startAngle(function(d){return        cScale(d[0]);}) .endAngle(function(d){return cScale(d[1]);});

vis.selectAll("g") .data(data) .enter() .append("path").attr("class", "path1") .attr("d", arc)     .style("fill", function(d){return d[2];}).attr("transform",     "translate(250,-300)").transition().duration(1000).delay(0).attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

};

function secondRing(data){
var arc2 = d3.svg.arc() .innerRadius(102) .outerRadius(110) .startAngle(function(d){return     cScale(d[0])+5;}) .endAngle(function(d){return cScale(d[1])+5;});

vis.selectAll("g") .data(data) .enter() .append("path").attr("class", "path2") .attr("d", arc2)     .style("fill", function(d){return d[2];}).attr("transform",     "translate(-600,30)").transition().duration(500).delay(0).attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
}

function thirdRing(data){
var arc3 = d3.svg.arc() .innerRadius(114) .outerRadius(150) .startAngle(function(d){return     cScale(d[0])+15;}) .endAngle(function(d){return cScale(d[1])+15;});

vis.selectAll("g") .data(data) .enter() .append("path").attr("class", "path3") .attr("d", arc3)     .style("fill", function(d){return d[2];}).attr("transform",     "translate(-600,-900)").transition().duration(2000).delay(0).attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
}

function fourthRing(data){
var arc4 = d3.svg.arc() .innerRadius(152) .outerRadius(170) .startAngle(function(d){return     cScale(d[0])+35;}) .endAngle(function(d){return cScale(d[1])+35;});

var test1 = vis.selectAll("g") .data(data) .enter();
var test2 = test1 .append("path") .attr("class", "path4") .attr("d", arc4) .style("fill",     function(d){return d[2];}).attr("transform",     "translate(-400,700)").transition().duration(1500).delay(0).attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
}




function func1(){
    sheet.insertRule(".path1 {-webkit-animation:spin1 4s linear infinite; z-index: 1; } ", 0);
}

function func2(){
    sheet.insertRule(".path2 {-webkit-animation:spin2 1s linear infinite; z-index: 0; } ", 0);
}

function func3(){
    sheet.insertRule(".path3 {-webkit-animation:spin3 6s linear infinite; z-index: 3; } ", 0);
}

function func4(){
    sheet.insertRule(".path4 {-webkit-animation:spin4 8s linear infinite; z-index: 2; } ", 0);
}


    var path4 = document.getElementsByClassName("path4");
    path4.onclick=function(){alert("hi");};




setTimeout(func1,1000);
setTimeout(func2,500);
setTimeout(func3,2000);
setTimeout(func4,1500);


d3.select("p").transition().duration(3000).delay(2000).style("opacity", 1);

</script>

</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
    50% { opacity: 0; } 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
    50% { opacity: 0; } 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin3 {
    50% { opacity: 0; } 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin4 {
    50% { opacity: 0; } 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); } 
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'xyzfont';
    src: url('font/Rebellion.otf'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
}

.companyName{
    position: fixed;
    left: 120px;
    bottom: 260px;
    font-size: 90pt;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: xyzfont, Georgia, Arial;
    color: #000740;
    line-height: 90px;
}

svg{
    padding-left: 400px;
    padding-top: 200px;
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: You removed `@-webkit-`, but did you also remove `-webkit-` infront of the `-webkit-transform` property in the keyframe animation?

Comment: easwee - I removed every instance of -webkit- from the index.html AND I tried removing "-webkit-" and "-webkit-transform" from the css, no luck.

Comment: IE does not currently support declarative animation of SVG, regardless of whether it is CSS animation keyframes or SVG animation elements.  The only way to animate SVG in IE is to create the animation frames in JavaScript (e.g., by using d3's transitions).